# Ktor server doesn't handle post requsets

Tags: rest, ktor

I hava a ktor server instance. When i make `GET` request it work normaly as i excpect, but when i make any `POST` request it falls into timeout and server logger doesn't write anything.
Some methods code

GET

```
    get(basePath.plus(GET_CONFIG_PATH)) {
        val config = configDao.getConfig()
        call.respond(config)
    }
```

POST

```
    post(basePath.plus(UPDATE_CONFIG_PATH)) {
        val config = call.receive<OnBoardingConfig>()
        configDao.updateConfig(config)
        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    }
```

1st method select some rows from db and the 2nd method updates some rows in db. DB user has all CRUD roghts.

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is just by looking at your code. Could you please locate the actual line of code that causes the timeout problem (Is it the `receive` call or a database update)?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman idk where problem located, because i have no errors in log. Actualy logger doens't log post requsets at all.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that ptoblem is under the ktors hood, but can't find it in YouTrack. After updating ktor 1.6.8 to 2.0.3 and kotlin 1.6.10 to 1.7.0 problem has gone.